# Paypal error while refunding

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have one problem related to refunding amount. I have integrated the code for refunding in woo-commerce word-press, here i have transaction id and and based on that i will refund, But when i passed the transaction id this was giving me error for partial refund.
And i was used that code for full transfer then it transfer the full amount.
Following is the error which i have getting,

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2015-02-20T10:42:44Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 601b94ea87ee1
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 51.0
    [BUILD] => 15295733
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10009
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction refused
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => You can not do a partial refund on this transaction
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

Please Any one help me soon...
Thanks,
In advance

Answer (score 4):

You have Payment Review enabled on your Sandbox account, which means that all incoming payments are placed on hold.  In the live environment, a PayPal agent would review the transaction within 24 hours and review it or release it; in the Sandbox environment, you must release it manually.  Until the hold has been released, you cannot perform a partial refund on the transaction -- you can only do a full refund.

You can release the payment by logging into the merchant's sandbox account (at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com), locating the transaction (under History) and clicking the "Details" link on it, then clicking either the "Accept" or "Deny" link at the bottom of the page.

You can disable Payment Review by following the steps below.  Once you disable Payment Review, any further payments that you process will not be placed on hold for Payment Review.

- Log into https://developer.paypal.com
- Go to Dashboard->Sandbox->Accounts
- Find your Sandbox merchant account in the list of accounts and click on it
- Click the Profile link that appears underneath it
- Click the Settings tab
- Click "Off" under Payment Review

Comment: Hello Sir,Thanks for your reply... can you please give me the detail path to do the setting?...Because I don't get 'Payment Review' section in given path.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue when upgrade PayPal API to v2.

PayPal refund API will alway response `NOT_AUTHORIZED` status when we use different currency for payer and merchant. It's should work on v1.

I have to create a new sandbox merchant account with exactly currency used. Then it works.

[image]

Reference: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-REST-API-issues/issues/301